# How to handle table which sorting and adding data parallel?

Tags: java, sorting, jxtable

I am facing problem of duplicate rows in the `JXTable`. If I sort the `JXTable` data while the new rows are being inserted in `JXTable`, the final result in `JXTable` shows duplicate rows that make invalid result in table. Even it also shows correct count of rows that has been inserted but some rows are completely missing whereas some rows are found duplicate in `JXTable`.

If I sort the `JXTable` after all data has been inserted successfully then it is showing correct data i.e no duplicate rows and no rows missing.

code example :
I have a method to which I am passing defaultTableModel  and here is am adding items in the table

```
public void addingItems(DefaultTableModel  defaultTableModel)
{
for(int i=0;i< numberofItems;i++){
Vector vobject = new Vector();
vobject.add("...");
vobject.add("xxx");
vobject.add("yyy");
...
..
vobject.add("");
defaultTableModel.addRow(vobject);
}
```

one the other hand I have adding code of sorting at tableHeader actionlistener

```
tableheader.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
     Vector data = defaultTableModel.getDataVector();   
     Collections.sort(data, new ColumnSorter(colIndex, ascending));
}
```

});

I have put code in the `synchronized` block but not getting success.

Please provide a better solution to handle this issue.

Comment: How are you adding data?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) *"or I have to do this one by one ?"* Doing them sequentially would seem to make a lot of sense.

Comment: You will better and quicker answers if you show a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Mr Thompson beat me on that one ;-)

Comment: @assylias  The advantage of copy/paste.  ;)

Comment: I am adding data throw model. Creating vector for each row and then adding that vector in tablemodel

Comment: Thanks Andrew and assylias for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have put code in the synchronized block but not getting success.

Because you have to handle synchronization not only in your sort handler block, but also on each modification operation.

For example:

```
  ... 
  vobject.add("");
  synchronized(monitor) {
    defaultTableModel.addRow(vobject);
  }
}
```

and

```
  ...
  Vector data = defaultTableModel.getDataVector();
  synchronized(monitor) {
    Collections.sort(data, new ColumnSorter(colIndex, ascending));
  }
}
```

In this case your UI could look somewhat unresponsive if you have a lot of data in your table because sort is N^2*logN. If you have somewhat about 200 entries - it wouldn't make a problem for you.